# Getarg function with 3 arguments in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have an update tp do on a code in Fortran 77 and I had the surprise to see a call to GETARG() function with 3 arguments:

```
CALL GETARG(IARG,CHARARG,INT2)
```

Of course it is not compiling with gfortran and I was wondering if suchsyntax really existed in Fortran 77 and what it meant?

Comment: No standard of Fortran defines a `getarg` intrinsic subroutine.  Do you have an idea of which compiler was targeted?  (Documentation for that compiler will tell you what the intrinsic there does.)

Comment: There is no GETARG in standard Fortran. What does the original compiler's manual say? Which compiler it even was?

Comment: ok I see, that's probably it, I am used to gfortran that's why I was puzzled.

Comment: Possibly the MS/DEC/Compaq/Intel compiler.  At a guess it is probably GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT.